# TailwindCSS Custom Theme

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, tailwind-css

I want to create some varient of theme and able to switch between them in tailwind CSS I found a video on youtube on this topic in JS [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MAtaT8BZEAo&t=431s&ab_channel=TailwindLabs) but i am using TS and a custom function called with opacity is not working properly. it is not showing color when using that function if we pass through var directly instead of custom function without applying opacity then it works

```
global.css

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {
  :root {
    --primary-color: #847869;
    --secondary-color: #fae1c3;

    --primary-background-color: #202020;
    --secondary-background-color: #1d1d1d;
    --accentColor: #91170c;

    --robotoMono: "Roboto Mono", monospace;
    --barlow: "Barlow", sans-serif;
  }
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.container {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```
tailwind.config.ts

import { type Config } from "tailwindcss";
import { fontFamily } from "tailwindcss/defaultTheme";

function withOpacity(variableName: string) {
  return ({ opacityValue }: { opacityValue: number | undefined }): string => {
    if (opacityValue !== undefined) {
      return `rgba(var(${variableName}), ${opacityValue})`;
    }
    return `rgb(var(${variableName}))`;
  };
}

export default {
  content: ["./src/**/*.tsx"],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ["var(--font-sans)", ...fontFamily.sans],
      },
      textColor: {
        skin: {
          base: "var( --primary-color)",
          // muted: withOpacity('--color-text-muted'),
          // inverted: withOpacity('--color-text-inverted'),
        },
      },
      backgroundColor: {
        skin: {
          withOpacity("--primary-background-color")
          // fill: withOpacity("--primary-background-color") as unknown as string,
          // 'button-accent': withOpacity('--color-button-accent'),
          // 'button-accent-hover': withOpacity('--color-button-accent-hover'),
          // 'button-muted': withOpacity('--color-button-muted'),
        },
      },
      gradientColorStops: {
        skin: {
          // hue: withOpacity('--color-fill'),
        },
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
} satisfies Config;
```

```
Type '(: any) => any' is not assignable to type 'string | RecursiveKeyValuePair<string, string>'.ts(2322)
```

```
⨯ ./src/styles/globals.css.webpack[javascript/auto]!=!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/css-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[12].oneOf[12].use[2]!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[12].oneOf[12].use[3]!./src/styles/globals.css
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (29:23)
Import trace for requested module:
./src/styles/globals.css.webpack[javascript/auto]!=!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/css-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[12].oneOf[12].use[2]!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[12].oneOf[12].use[3]!./src/styles/globals.css
./src/styles/globals.css
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the return type for the opacity custom function first of all.
Also the skin property inside backgroundColor should be a key value pair, something like this:

```
function withOpacity(variableName: string): string {
  return ({ opacityValue }: { opacityValue: number | undefined }): string => {
    if (opacityValue !== undefined) {
      return `rgba(var(${variableName}), ${opacityValue})`;
    }
    return `rgb(var(${variableName}))`;
  };
}

export default {
  content: ["./src/**/*.tsx"],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ["var(--font-sans)", ...fontFamily.sans],
      },
      textColor: {
        skin: {
          base: "var( --primary-color)",
          // muted: withOpacity('--color-text-muted'),
          // inverted: withOpacity('--color-text-inverted'),
        },
      },
      backgroundColor: {
        skin: {
          main: withOpacity("--primary-background-color")
          // fill: withOpacity("--primary-background-color") as unknown as string,
          // 'button-accent': withOpacity('--color-button-accent'),
          // 'button-accent-hover': withOpacity('--color-button-accent-hover'),
          // 'button-muted': withOpacity('--color-button-muted'),
        },
      },
      gradientColorStops: {
        skin: {
          // hue: withOpacity('--color-fill'),
        },
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
} satisfies Config;
```

You can use this repository as reference
https://gist.github.com/vladdu/88f0c032fbca4ccca3456e92de7b80a7

Comment: it did not work properly it gave the typescript error
Type '({ opacityValue }: { opacityValue: number | undefined; }) => string' is not assignable to type 'string'.